# Colocar colunas apenas no campo Detail no JasperStudio

Tags: jasper

Possuo um relatório criado no JasperStudio, preciso colocar apenas colunas no campo Detail, porém quando configuro para ter duas colunas o relatório os campos de agrupamento também acabam se configurando com duas colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Modelo que gostaria de ter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agora com o exemplo esta mais atrativo. Bom meu caro existe mesmo a necessidade de os números serie fiquem lateralmente ?. Mesmo que utlize um subreport nao vai atender esse layout, uma lista tambem nao iria servir, nem tão pouco um crosstable. Imaginando que cada serie seja um registro filho do defeito, eu nao possuo conhecimento necessario para te ajudar nesta tarefa, o padrão e que cada registro apareceça em uma linha e caso mude o layout para colunas iria parecer um em cada coluna, vou ver se consigo te ajudar, vou dar uma pesquisada mas a principio bem dificil essa sua questão

Comment: Amigo tenta usar um list e muda a ordem de impressão(Print Order) para horizontal veja se atende a sua necessidade

Comment: @DenisBenjamim como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: voce poe um List no seu relatorio e procura entre as abas do componente que este  menu estará disponivel

Answer (score 0):

Amigo voce deve por os componentes apenas na primeira coluna sem passar para a as colunas que tem linhas vermelhas, na sua imagem seu componentes estão ultrapassando a linha.
Lembrando que o metodo para varias colunas irão repetir todos os campos em suas colunas, para uma melhor resposta poste mais detalhes do seu problema de forma mais clara, vou postar a baixo como é o meu que tem 3 colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu consegui colocar as colunas tranquilamente, porém como mostrei na imagem eu tenho campos de GROUP BY e nesses campos esta indo as colunas também sendo que preciso que as colunas fiquem apenas no campo Detail, isso seria possível?

Comment: Sua imagem mostra Fields acredio que na banda detail , e tudo que fica no detail vai repetir em cada coluna.Agora sobre os group by voce esta usando ele no SQL ou os group by do proprio jasper?. Acho que voce precisa deixar de forma mais clara o seu objetivo, pois não estou conseguindo entender, se possivel faça um pequeno exemplo do que deseja mesmo que seja no paint.

Comment: O group by que usei foi o do próprio Jasper, alterei a pergunta com o modelo que gostaria de alcançar.